# UIcollectionview display different cell after certain row

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I need to create a UIcollectionview with grids of cells with 3 cells per row. After a certain amount of cells, lets say 60, I need to display a big cell with image view cell 61(different set of data). But with creating this 61st cell of image, my normal data on 61st will be merged into this image cell, is there any way to calculate it without compromising my array of data . Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code , So that helps more to figure-out where is the problem...

Comment: there is an array of data of objects [users], so the numbers of users will be big. I need to display the users info on the cell1 which display 3 per row. On every increment of cell 61 I need to display a big banner image view which the data is just an URL. Now the problem is I can display the cell 61 image banner, but in the same time the 61st [users] is display into the cell 61 image banner too, so how can I prevent the [users] to display into the banner cell?

Comment: Maybe you can use a section header for the 61st cell.

Comment: @FryAnEgg could you provide some guide or code on how to show a section header every 60 cells displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the data source part:

```
var items = [Item]()

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    let numberOfSections = 60/(items.count+1) + 1
    return numberOfSections
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           let numberOfSections = 60/(items.count+1) + 1

   if section != numberOfSections - 1 {
       return 60
   }
   let numberOfItems = items.count%60
   return numberOfItems
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {   
        let itemIndex = indexPath.section * 60 + indexPath.row
        let item = items[itemIndex]
        // set cell from item … 
}
```

Then  you need to provide the header cell using UICollectionViewDelegate:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplaySupplementaryView view: UICollectionReusableView, forElementKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Search SO for 'willDisplaySupplementaryView' will show you how to implement this. Good luck!